# Long Door Strike Plates

Tags: doors, door-frame

I'm currently exploring options for door strike plates and have noticed that the ones available at Home Depot and Amazon tend to be rather short and small. Recently, I came across a YouTube video featuring a longer strike plate used in a home-building project.

Is a longer strike plate generally considered better? If so, could you provide guidance on where I might find these longer strike plates for purchase?

[image: Long strike plate]

Comment: Shopping questions like where to get are not on topic here.  I would search for security strike plates or maybe make your own.  That we can help with.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour].

Comment: Its a matter of preference.  If you have multiple holes spaced out, you can use multiple strike plates or a single long one.  Because the hole spacing will be custom, it is unlikely that you will find any.  You can get them made.

Comment: "Better" for what? Even if it wasn't closed for "shopping", it would be closed as "opinion based".

Answer (score 3):

No, a long strike plate isn't inherently better. It's most often a repair piece for past damage to the frame, or for cases where there are existing strike borings in the wrong places. If you are looking for a security improvement there are better options in higher- security strikes.

Comment: If you must, there are online vendors (google “door strike plate”), or if you’re lucky, brick and mortar specialists nearby.